# How to get default log details of lotusscript agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I developed an notes application called "agent monitoring" which will trigger email daily when the schedule agent prints an error in the `log.nsf` file.

> 2017-03-28 09:39:42   AMgr: Agent ('GoSAP' in '\DomApps\GoSAP.nsf') error message: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'.

I search for details using an "error message" regular expression string in the log and then send email.

Now I would like to handle when the agent hangs.  I think it can be done if we get details from the default agent log [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C2Lb.png).

Can somebody please guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: It's not best practice to write in the log.nsf, an application log is much better. See the OpenLog project at openntf: https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenLog/summary

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer : Thanks for your prompt reply. I don't write the above error message in the log. That is default format written on the log by agentmanager when agent encounters error. How we can know the scheduled agent hand using lotusscript?

Comment: My remark about application log was for "2017-03-28 09:39:42 AMgr: Agent ('GoSAP' in '\DomApps\GoSAP.nsf') error message: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2033'."
I search briefly how to get (programmatically ) the Agent log (but as in https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20531806/Open-Agent-Log-using-LotusScript.html it doesn't seems to be possible)

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer: I got another idea of getting whether the agent run successfully or not using this notes.ini setting. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21228274

Comment: Yes this is a good idea, especially if you already parse the log.nsf, you will have all the searched information in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agent log can be accessed this way.

- For eaach database that you are interested in, set up a [NotesNoteCollection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESNOTECOLLECTION_CLASS.html) with [SelectAgents](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SELECTAGENTS_PROPERTY_NC.html)=true and call [BuildCollection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_BUILDCOLLECTION_METHOD_NC.html).
- Iterate through the collection with [getFirstNoteId](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFIRSTNOTEID_METHOD_NC.html)/[getNextNoteId](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETNEXTNOTEID_METHOD_NC.html) and get the agent notes via [GetDocumentByID](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/reference/r_domino_Database_getDocumentByID.html)
- Use [NotesDXLExporter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDXLEXPORTER_CLASS.html) with the agent note as input to generate XML, then parse the XML and read the <trigger type> and/or <agent name> data to determine if you care about the agent. If it's a scheduled agent that you want to monitor, then look at the <runlog> data.

Comment: Hi Richard, Apologies for late reply. I will parse the DXL as you explained and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Richard, Awesome answer. I have implemented your solution successfully. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]==> look at @Richard Schwartz response, it seems possible with NotesDXLExporter.

[Original response]
This is not possible programmatically in Notes.

Remark: if you have a client running, you can use sendkey (windows dll not the notes function that is buggy) to display the log.

This question has also been asked years ago in [experts-exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20531806/Open-Agent-Log-using-LotusScript.html)
also without solution there.